# Permutation into chained transpositions?

Tags: permutations

I know that every permutation can be factored as a product of transpositions.

I wonder if every permutation can be factored as product of *chained* transpositions ?

For example

```
[5,1,3,0,4,2] = [(3,2),(2,5),(5,0)]
                    \__/  \__/
```

And, if so, starting with an arbitrary element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: The product of chained transpositions is always a cycle.

Comment: Ok. I guess the answer is no, since not all permutations are cycles.

Comment: @PoorStandard Exactly.